# How to Display labels in google earth

Tags: kml, arcgis, google-earth

I have exported data of ArcGIS in `.kml` format. And I am able to display it in Google Earth. But how can I display labels to this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

KML placemarks will display labels if they have the `<name>` element defined.

In the example below the place label would show as "Washington DC".

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Placemark>
    <name>Washington DC</name>
    <description>Welcome to the Capitol Building</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-77.00618236,38.88986074</coordinates>
    </Point>
 </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Sounds like the name element is not being populated during export. Check export options if name property can be generated otherwise you will have to edit the KML some other way.

UPDATE: If have features with a Line or Polygon geometry then the names will not display by default as they do for point data. If want name to be display for non-point data then need to create a `<MultiGeometry>` element and include a Point where you want the label to appear.